# Strange file name in /var/lib/mysql/databasename/ folder

Tags: file, ubuntu-12.04, delete-file

I have a `databasename` database which has both MyISAM and InnoDB tables. I have just realized that there are 2 strange files: `#sql-942_3aa8.MYI` and `#sql-942_3aa8.MYD` with total size of several Gbs.

I'd like to ask whether it is safe to delete these 2 files? I don't see any file name staring with `#` in my other databases.

(I ask this question because my disk space is running low (So not convenient to backup the database), deleting these 2 files helps complete my currently running process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have deleted these files and the database is still functioning normally